# Unable to access permission(s) within java code from manifest

Tags: android

manifest.java :

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package com.mfi;

public final class Manifest {
    public static final class permission {
        public static final String C2D_MESSAGE="permission.C2D_MESSAGE";
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GPS_PROVIDER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But I'm unable to request any permissions from MainActivity as below code throws compiler error L: `cannot resolve symbol : ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        1);
```

How to update manifest.java to generate the permission I'm attempting to access, in this case `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` ?

Comment: you might have imported  the wrong Manifest class. Check your imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the below package for Manifest class,

**import android.Manifest;**

You can easily access the permission *Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION* and others too